# What does it mean when a dish or product is described as "(insert culture/tradition) style"?

Tags: regional-cuisine

For example, if I have fried eggs and toast, it's just fried eggs. But if I add chorizo on the side, suddenly it transforms into "Spanish style" fried eggs.

There are many examples.  When is a food product described as "__________ style?"

Comment: I really don't think this is a rule, and it's also pretty opinion based (hard to answer definitively) - "style" can mean different things, and cultural references can be tricky.  Generally speaking, I would expect the answer is "no" - "spanish style" might mean "how things are done in Spain" or else "using Spain-specific ingredients" - using chorizo might be one way, using manchego cheese another, adding potatoes to your eggs ("spanish tortilla") a third, depending on dish and style and culture (both originating and imitating) and a bunch of other possible factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the word "style" to a dish or food item is a way of giving a nod to a particular culture or tradition when the end product is not authentic. While we can debate the idea of "authentic" in another space, generally the term "style" might mean that a technique was employed, or an ingredient was used, but that the final product is not of the culture or tradition being referenced.  This sort of labeling is generally done for marketing purposes, be it at home for your family, in a restaurant, or in a retail situation.

Answer (score 0):

The Italians also have spicy Chorizo style sausages, so perhaps you couldn't get away with calling that a Spanish style pizza.  However, I believe that you have a good point, and anything that adds a bit of flair and ingenuity to something is great.  Spanish eggs - why not?